# Jmeter: Parameterize the headers in "HTTP header manager" using "CSV data set config"

Tags: jmeter

Jmeter: I tried to Parameterize the headers(pass about 5 dynamic headers) in "HTTP header manager" using  "CSV data set config". But i could not, can anybody help me??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the CSV data setup variables in the HTTP header manager.
Can you be more specific on where you're stuck?

YouTube tutorial on using CSV data with JMeter:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aEJNc3TW-g8

Blog that explains exactly what to do:
http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config

Answer (score 3):

If you need to add 5 dynamic headers one by one, i.e. one header per request just change the value on each consecutive request - it's pretty easy doable, just place your [CSV Data Set Config](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config) as a child of required request, the same for HTTP Header Manager.

If you need to add all 5 headers **before** any testing starts - you'll need to consider do it in a separate thread group or use combination of [Loop Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) with [Once Only Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller)

If none above is applicable to your test scenario try updating it and provide as much information as you can.